# Como executar comandos no Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Eu preciso executar o comando: **gradle -q dependencies** para verificar conflitos de biblioteca no Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso esteja usando o `Android Studio` no MacOSX:

Utilize a barra de acesso ao `Terminal` e abra uma nova sessão:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No terminal navegue até o `root` do seu projeto e utilize os comandos usando `./gradlew`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu só tenho os arquivos gradle, gradlew no workspace, não aparece estes arquivos dentro do projeto, então os comandos não funcionam.. oque fazer?

Comment: Quais arquivos tem na sua árvore de diretório do projeto?

Comment: tem a workspace inteira, se eu importo somente o gradle do projeto, o modulo para dar run fica vazio e também não importa as classes src

Answer (score 0):

Para acrescentar resposta do usuário iTSangar voce pode acessar o console do gradle ao lado direito da mesma barra do terminal[image: Linha Azul]